# Winform Composite Control Project?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to have a single project which allow to include a custom custom control within another custom control ?

**Update:** of course I'm not asking about how to put a custom control on a winform!!! But if I can create put a CUSTOM user CONTROL inside ANOTHER CUSTOM user CONTROL within the SAME PROJECT.

Comment: Include a custom *what*?

Comment: Yes. You can do this. Have you tried? What difficulties are you experiencing? (Please don't get frustrated; I'm sure people honestly didn't understand what you were referring to.)

Comment: Russian dolls are supported.  You have to compile the code before you get the control on the top of the toolbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you're able to do this. In fact you're able to put a custom control inside another custom control the same way you'd do it on a form (it's essentially the same while editing). You might as well base your custom control off another class (or custom control), but not all will support the built in gui editor (so you might just see an error message but the code will still work).